# Angular 2 ngFor don't update data

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have Component.

```
@Component({
selector: 'todo-list',
directives: [TodoItemRenderer],
providers: [TodoService],
template:
    '<div>'+
        '<ul class="list-group">'+
            '<li [(ngClass)]="item.class" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="#item of items">' +
               '<todo-item-renderer [todo] = "item"></todo-item-renderer>'+
            '</li>'+
        '</ul>'+
    '</div>'

})
```

Also, this is the data I have in the service

```
items: TodoModel[] = [
    new TodoModel("sleep", "Completed"),
    new TodoModel("eat", "In progress"),
    new TodoModel("code", "In the plan")
];
```

When I add new element in this array

```
service.items,push(new TodoModel());
```

List doesn't update. What is the problem?

Comment: How the items are passed to the `todo-list` component? Could you share the whole code of `todo-list`

Comment: Hint: If you use backticks around your template you can create multiline strings instead of concatenating single strings.

Comment: Where do you have the code `service.items,push(new TodoModel());`? Where is it called from?

Answer (score 0):

> **ASSUMPTION** you are using Release Candidate and not Beta

There was an update to ngFor so you will need to change

```
*ngFor="#item of items"
```

to:

```
*ngFor="let item of items"
```

You should be seeing an error indicating this within your browser's console explaining that this change should be made.

Comment: So i get EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
What i should do?

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Yes , sure 
*ngFor="let tem of items">'

Comment: I check , the array of data is updating. But data view isn't. What i should do?